# Jquery have parent do something only once parent and child not hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, parent

I'm having a parent element flip once its child is hovered, which is working. I can get it to flip back when the child is no longer moused over, but I'm having trouble getting the parent to flip back once the user is no longer hovering over the child OR it's parent. Here's my attempt (fyi I'm very new to this):

```
$(function (){
    var parentOfChild;
    $(".bannerBottom").on("mouseenter", function(event){ // this section works
        parentOfChild = $(event.target).parent().attr('id');
        $(this).parent().css({
            'transition': '1s',
            'transform': 'rotateY(180deg)'

        });
    });
    $(".bannerBottom").on("mouseleave", function(){ // my problem is in this section
        if (mouse not over .bannerBottom || parentOfChild) { //<-- what I'm trying to do but don't know how
            $('#' + parentOfChild).css({
                'transition': '1s',
                'transform': 'rotateY(0deg)'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

TY for the responses so far, I'm reading the .is() link now, in the meanwhile here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4ajuqwq/16/).

For anyone in the future here's the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4ajuqwq/17/) with timster's solution.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: Does the parent element enclose the child? Or is one of them outside the document flow (e.g., absolute-positioned)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the child is part of the parent's flow root (that is the parent element encloses the child element) then you can just watch for the mouse leave on the parent.

```
  $(".bannerBottom").parent().on("mouseleave", function(event){
    $(this).css({
            'transition': '1s',
            'transform': 'rotateY(0deg)'
        });
 });
```

(Also, there's no need to search the DOM (with $("#" + var) ) from the mouse leave event - that is slow. The event already knows its triggering element.)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try this /facepalm but it worked beautifully ty!

Answer (score 0):

use `.is()` with negation in `if` statement https://api.jquery.com/is/